# What is the "non-static method" error and how does "this" work?

Tags: java, oop, compiler-errors, instance-variables, class-members

I have a couple of EXTREMELY basic Java questions that I would like to finally understand, once and for all. I have the following short piece of code:

```
public class VeryBasicJava{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int x = 3;
        int y = 4;
        swapMe(x, y);
    }
    private void swapMe(int a, int b){
        int a;
        int b;
        int tmp = a;
        this.a = b;
        this.b = a;
    }
}
```

When I compile, I get the dreaded "non-static method swapMe(int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context" error. Also, I get "a is already defined in swapMe(int,int)" and "b is already defined in swapMe(int,int)"

What I need to finally get through my thick skull, is the "non-static method" error, how (why) it is caused, and how to avoid it.

Further, I was under the assumption that you could do what I am attempting to do with my 'a' and 'b' variables in the "swapMe" method. I thought I could pass in an 'a' and 'b', but also create new variables 'a' and 'b', and reference them with "this" keyword.

I know this is extremely basic, but these two "issues" are two of the main sticking points I have with Java, and for some reason, cannot seem to properly learn.

Thank you all, for taking the time to read this. Have a great day.

Comment: good question that a lot of early java programmers go through : )

Comment: Good question that most people will just provide code and not actually explain what is going on.

Comment: Could people stop giving *examples*? The questioner doesn't need working code, he needs someone to explain object-orientated programming concepts.

Answer (score 11):

That means that the method `swapMe()` is an *instance* method and you need an instance of the `VeryBasicJava` class to invoke it, like this:

```
VeryBasicJava instance = new VeryBasicJava();
int x = 3; int y = 4;
instance.swapMe(x, y);
```

Alternatively,  you could declare `swapMe()` as `static`, in that way you won't need to create an instance first:

```
private static void swapMe(int a, int b)
```

Comment: But, swapMe is in the same class as main, which is the class VeryBasicJava. Why do I need to create an instance of VeryBasicJava in order to call a method from within itself? To me, this is equivalent to saying instance.x = 3, and instance.y = 4.


I guess I should also state that I am a procedural person, I learned programming with C.

Comment: Because you're calling it from inside a static method.

If you called swapMe from another non-static method you wouldn't need the instance of the class to invoke it.

Comment: Java is perplexing, that makes absolutely no sense to me. I tell ya, C is MUCH more straight forward than Java ever thought about.

Comment: @Brian in Java (and most object-oriented languages) we make a distinction regarding the methods in a class: the _instance_ methods, which have access to both the _instance_ and _class_ members of the class and need to be invoked on an _instance_ of the class. And the _class_ methods, which have access only to the _class_ members of the class, and don't need an _instance_ to be invoked

Comment: @Brian in your code, the `swapMe()` method is an _instance_ method, and therefore can not be invoked without referring first to an instance of the class `VeryBasicJava`. On the other hand, methods like `Math.sqrt()` are `static`, meaning that they belong to a class, not an instance, and don't need an instance to be invoked

Comment: @Oscar That made no sense to me. Because swapMe() belongs to VeryBasicJava, we must do something special in order to use it.  But, because Math.sqrt() does not belong to VeryBasicJava, we can use it without any extra code whatsoever? That is the most confusing thing I have ever heard. And I'm always hearing Java people talking about how confusing and un-intuitive malloc is.

Comment: @Brian the confusion is understandable, since you come from a procedural background. You need to go back to the basics, to really grok object-oriented programming - for now, I'd recommend you read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html),from the Java tutorial.

Comment: @Brian, part of it is that _static_ methods (including e.g. `Math.sqrt`) work exactly the way you expect, but when your class has its own fields and meanings, then instance methods let you do things that you couldn't with static methods.

Comment: -1: This is an example, not an explanation. You're using terms like instance and static without explaining what you mean, hence the protracted comment chat.

Answer (score 5):

You have just a few minor problems. You mentioned in a comment that you have some experience with C, so I’ll try to draw some basic analogies. A `static` method (such as `main`) behaves like an ordinary C function. A non-`static` method, however, takes a hidden parameter: `this`, which refers to an *object* on which that method is to operate. When you write a method such as this:

```
private void swapMe(int a, int b) {
    // ...
```

It really means something like this:

```
private void swapMe(VeryBasicJava this, int a, int b){
    //              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // ...
```

Because the `this` parameter is treated specially, there is a special syntax for calling non-`static` methods on objects:

```
    myInstance.swapMe(someA, someB);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^  ^^^^^
//     this             a      b
```

And because `swapMe` is not declared `static`, it expects to be called like the above.

The fact that `main` is declared inside the `VeryBasicJava` class does not mean that you automatically have a `VeryBasicJava` *object*. Again, because `main` is `static`, it is just like an ordinary C function:

```
void VeryBasicJava_main(...) {
    // ...
```

In order to *create* an instance of an object, you use `new`:

```
VeryBasicJava vbj = new VeryBasicJava();
```

This is analogous to `malloc` in C:

```
VeryBasicJava *vbj = malloc(sizeof(VeryBasicJava));
VeryBasicJava_construct(vbj);
```

With an instance, you can invoke a method:

```
vbj.swapMe(spam, eggs);
```

Your other issue is twofold: one of *scope*, and of *members*. Scope, as you may know, refers to *where* a variable exists. Take this function:

```
1: private void swapMe(int a, int b) {
2:     int a;
3:     int b;
4:     int tmp = a;
5:     this.a = b;
6:     this.b = a;
7: }
```

When this method is called, the following things happen:

1. `a` and `b` are created, given the values specified in the call to `swapMe`.
2. A new `a` is created, local to `swapMe`, with the default value `0`. This `a` *hides* the parameter `a`, and there is no way to differentiate them.
3. A new `b` is created, also strictly local. It too has the default `0` value, and hides the parameter `b`.
4. `tmp` is created, and its value is set to that of the newly declared `a`, so it too is `0`.
5. [*see below*]
6. [*see below*]
7. The locals `a` and `b` cease to exist, as do the parameters `a` and `b`.

In lines 5 and 6, you attempt to use the syntax `this.a` to refer to the local `a` rather than the parameter. Though this syntax exists in Java, it does not do what you mean. Parameters are treated just the same as local variables, so rather than differentiating between those two categories, `this.a` differentiates between locals and *members*. Now, what are members? Well, say your class declaration contains variable declarations:

```
class VeryBasicJava {

    private int a;
    private int b;

    // ...

}
```

That’s just like member declarations in a C `struct`:

```
struct VeryBasicJava {
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

What this means is that when you create an instance of `VeryBasicJava`:

```
VeryBasicJava vbj = new VeryBasicJava();
```

That instance has its own variables `a` and `b`, which can be used in any non-`static` method:

```
public void print() {
    System.out.println("a is " + a);
    System.out.println("b is " + b);
}
```

If you have a local variable with the same name as a member, then you must use `this` to explicitly state that you want to refer to the member. This complete program illustrates how to declare, use, and differentiate between members and locals.

```
class VeryBasicJava {

    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VeryBasicJava vbj = new VeryBasicJava();
        vbj.a = 3;
        vbj.b = 4;
        vbj.c = 5;
        vbj.print(1);
    }

    public void print(int a) {
        int b = 2;
        System.out.println("a is " + a);
        System.out.println("b is " + b);
        System.out.println("c is " + c);
        System.out.println("this.a is " + this.a);
        System.out.println("this.b is " + this.b);
        System.out.println("this.c is " + this.c);
    }

}
```

It will produce this output:

```
a is 1
b is 2
c is 5
this.a is 3
this.b is 4
this.c is 5
```

I hope these examples and explanations are helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your problems stem from not understanding how the object-orientated paradigm works.

The idea is that you define a class, which is a "type of thing". From that class, you create instances, which are effectively examples of that type of thing.

> For example, when you create a class "Wallet", that defines how your
>   system will treat wallets (i.e. what they can do, and what you can do
>   with them). You can now create multiple different *instances* of
>   wallets, that store different values, but still work the same way.
>   (e.g. "myWallet" and "yourWallet" are both Wallets, so you can take
>   money out and put money in etc, but if I check the money in
>   yourWallet, I get a value of 50, whereas if I check the value in
>   myWallet, I get a value of 20)

Now, "*static*" methods belong to the *class*. This means that they can't access members variables specific to the class. For example, if I'm keeping track of every wallet in my system, that value doesn't belong to any particular wallet in the class, but it's still involved with that class, so we make it static.

> To use my example, if you have two objects of type "Wallet", and one
>   has its "cash" value set to 30, and the other has its cash value set
>   to "25", a static function can't access both values, so it can't
>   access either. You have to give it a particular wallet to access.

The advantage of this method over C's approach is that it ties related functionality together. For example, if you see a C array of ints, you don't *really* know what they are intended to represent and may do something unexpected with them. But if I give you a Java array of Wallets, you also get the methods that influence how you interact with them. (This is a really stripped down explanation of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29))

**One of the principle issues with Java is that it ties *everything* to a class**. This causes a problem for the main method, which has to start the program, because it has no instances yet, but must still be part of the class. Therefore the main method must always be static. This tends to confuse new programmers, as invariably the first thing you do within the main method is create an instance of the class it's "inside".

In your example, you've got no "specific" data. Everything's inside the methods, which means you're effectively trying to write procedural code in Java. You can do this (just declare everything static), but the language will fight you, and you'll write very bad code.

When I was originally starting out with Java, **I effectively treated the main() method of a class as if it wasn't part of the class.** Conceptually, it helped, because you stop thinking of the non-static stuff as something that's already there (which is your main issue). But my recommendation to you is [try reading through this](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/how_to/java_for_c_programmers.shtml). But there are some very good transition courses out there for learning object-orientated programming, and you may want to invest in them.

Comment: Ok, According to this (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) article, static values are common to all objects created from a class. So, why wouldn't [from your example] a static method me accessible from all objects created from the class? If "cash" is static, and "checkCash()" is static, then it should work the same, and give me the same answer for every wallet created ... correct???

Comment: Yes, you're correct there. static methods can be accessed by any instance (see numberOfBicycles in that document). But what you're doing in the question above is accessing a NON-STATIC (instance) member function "swapMe" from a static method: "main", which is the other way around, and that won't work, because there's nothing stopping swapMe from accessing the specific instance members that won't exist without an instance.
The error is "accessing non-static method from static context", **not** "accessing static method from non-static context"

Answer (score 1):

Classes are a template for OBJECTS.  An instance of a class (i.e. and object) has its own version of variables and methods that are non-static.

static methods and fields **are not tied to any specific instance of a class**.

So it makes no sense to invoke a class instance method from a static method, without the instance on which you want to invoke the method.  In your example, `this` is a reference to an instance, but you have no instance....

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, when you create a function, it creates its own little stack for all of its variables. Its arguments are included in that stack - so, your stack looks like this:

```
    int a; //this is the first argument
    int b; //this is the second argument
    int a; //this is the first line of your function
    int b; //this is the second line of your function
```

That's why you're getting an issue - the a and b you declare after your arguments are conflicting with your arguments, not "this.a" and "this.b".

Your first question has already been answered.

Answer (score 1):

As the fix's been provided, I would like to add:

*static methods can only call other static methods and access only static variables directly* (in java).

To call non-static methods, you have create an instance of that class and call the methods then.

Answer (score 0):

swapMe needs an instance of VeryBasicJava to invoke it.  Static does not.

From outside that object, you could call:  VeryBasicJava.main(args).

From outside the object, you would need to do (new VeryBasicJava()).swapMe(a,b) to invoke that method.

The reason you are getting errors inside of swapMe is because you are defining those variables twice.  The signature line declared them in that namespace for you.  In that method, you already have an int a.  Then on the first line, you declare int a again.

What you want to do in your swap is something like this:

```
 private void swapMe(int a, int b){
    int tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
 }
```

Of course the variables a and b only exist in that method so as soon as the method ends your work is lost.  If you wanted to keep it, make the variables class variables and provide getters and setters for them.